# How to configure two USB2ethernet to connect two BBB based embedded linux board

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have two usb2ethernet and two BBB based custom boards,
I want to connect to both of them using ssh from my Ubuntu machine,

I am able to connect to one but for other one I am not able to ping,
I feel it has something to do with the routing and netmask but I am not able to figure it out,

1st interface is eth1 (usb2ether connector 1)
2st interface is eth2 (usb2ether connector 2)

Here is my `/etc/network/interface` file configuration content,

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
          address 192.168.2.1
          netmask 255.255.255.15

    auto eth2
    iface eth2 inet static
          address 192.168.2.17
          netmask 255.255.255.240

    post-up service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

I know `255.255.255.15` doesn't work :( that's what i was trying.
Here is my route table,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.9.66.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.9.66.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.16    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Any suggestion/hint would help,

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected two usb2ethernet and two BBB based boards directly, change netmask to `255.255.255.240` on first usb2ethernet.

You don't need restart isc-dhcp-server. If your BBB based boards must get ip addresses via dhcp you can configure dhcp server properly for two networks `192.168.2.0/28` and `192.168.2.16/28`. DHCP server must start at system boot.